# Deny specific users in VSFTPD

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, sftp, vsftpd

I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with VSFTPD. I want to deny certain users from connection via SFTP to my server.
So far I have only found Q&A (here on stackexchange and on the internet in general) regarding allowing certain users to connect and denying all others, but this is not suitable for me as I have too many users with allowed access and only few users are forbidden.

My question is: How can I deny connection to specific users in VSFTPD?

Comment: Use [pam_listfile](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_listfile).

Answer (score 2):

Enter the user name in `/etc/vsftpd/ftpusers` so that particular user will be denied for sftp or ftp connections.